# Fixing bash for user

Tags: linux, bash, kali-linux

I am using Kali Linux, and somehow I've screwed up bash for a specific user. As the affected user, bash does not show the current path, just the $. Additionally, history and autocomplete do not work. Pressing arrow keys adds ^[[A to the line, and pressing tab to autocomplete just inputs a regular tab.

I've tried restoring the default .bashrc with cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/ but that had no effect.

This is forcing me to use superuser for everything and I'd rather not do that. How can I fix this?

Comment: In addition to `~/.bashrc`, check on `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Is that user still using bash? Checked $SHELL or /etc/passwd?

Comment: … or explicitly run new `bash` from within this suspicious shell and compare.